# Trouble converting an icon object to Image using ResourceManager.GetObject

Tags: c#

I'm reading an icon filename from an xml file located in Resources. I'm able to capture the Object called temp which is my icon but I'm having difficulty converting this to an Image. Any suggestions?

```
    private void GenerateMenusFromXML(XmlNode rootNode, ToolStripMenuItem menuItem)
    {
        // todo implement image generation
        // need to rid hardcoding of the dll filename
        Assembly b = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"MainMenuEnhanced.dll"); 

        ToolStripItem item = null;
        ToolStripSeparator separator = null;
        //
        foreach (XmlNode node in rootNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (node.Attributes["Text"].Value == "-")
            {
                separator = new ToolStripSeparator();
                menuItem.DropDownItems.Add(separator);
            }
            else
            {
                item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
                item.Name = node.Attributes["Name"].Value;
                item.Text = node.Attributes["Text"].Value;
                string str = node.Attributes["Image"].Value;
                if (str != "")
                {
                    // Object is an icon....
                    Object test = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(str);
                    // trouble occurs here when trying to cast to an image
                    item.Image = Image test;
                }

                menuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item);

                if (node.Attributes["FormLocation"] != null)
                    item.Tag = node.Attributes["FormLocation"].Value;

                // add an event handler to the menu item added
                if (node.Attributes["OnClick"] != null)
                {
                    FindEventsByName(item, this.Form, true, "MenuItemOn", node.Attributes["OnClick"].Value);
                }

                GenerateMenusFromXML(node, (ToolStripMenuItem)menuItem.DropDownItems[menuItem.DropDownItems.Count - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?  Is `Objest test` equal to `null`?

Comment: Any error returns? or nothing at all even image = null?

Comment: Object test returns null but does throw an error - not even the next line. I have converted by .ico files to .bmp files and the code section works fine and places the .bmp images in the menu.